# Doctrine, SQLite and Enums

Tags: mysql, sqlite, symfony, enums, doctrine

We have an application running on Symfony 2.8 with a package named "liip/functional-test-bundle". We plan on using PHP Unit to run functional tests on our application, which uses MySQL for it's database.

The 'functional test bundle' package allows us to use the entities as a schema builder for an in-memory SQLite database, which is very handy because:

- It requires zero configuration to run
- It's extremely fast to run tests
- Our tests can be run independently from each test and the development data

Unfortunately, some of our entities use 'enums' which is not supported by SQLite, and our technical lead has opted to keep existing enums whilst refraining from using them anymore.

Ideally we need this in the project sooner rather than later, so the team can start writing new tests in the future to help maintain the stability of the application.

I have 3 options at this point, but I need help choosing the correct one and performing it correctly:

- Convince the technical lead that enums are a bad idea and lookup tables could instead be used (Which may cost time where the workload is already high)
- Switch to using MySQL for the testing database. (This will require additional configuration for our tests to run, and may be slower)
- Have doctrine detect when enums are used on a SQLite driver, and switch them  out for strings. (I would have no idea how to do this, but this is, in my opinion, the most ideal solution)

Which action is the best, and how should I carry it out?